# React Native, iOS, Google Signin will redirect to google.com if you install FBSDK as well

Tags: react-native, google-signin, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

If you install Google Signin, https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin , then you follow setup instructions from Google. At this step, you can do the signin well.

After that, you install FBSDK as well, https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk , then you follow setup instructions from Facebook. At this step, you will be **redirected to google.com** .

Answer (score 0):

open your `AppDelegate.m`, existing code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

modify it to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                             annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                  ]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                                                    openURL:url
                                          sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                 annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
      ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```